# Mahapps , icons not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

Posting this along with GitHub , may be someone from here has faced the same issue. I tried today with various options but was unable to get this working.

I have installed the MahApps.Metro from nugget. After that I installed the MahApps.Metro.Resources as well. This created a folder called resources in my project. I use the icons.xaml file in my window resources. I used some icons in the buttons of my usercontrol (embedded in main window within a content control). But when I run the icons do not appear. only the gray circle is visible.

I opened the icons.xaml and saw the Fill property where Fill={DynamicResource BlackBrush} is error out. If I change the fill to Fill="Black" then I can see the icons. But if the Accent is Dark it creates an issue as icons color do not change dynamically.

Based on the feedback in GitHub I  tried creating a small WPF sample. I added nugget Mahapps.metro and Mahapps.metro.resources I created a window, refrenced all MahApps.Metro xaml with the resources xaml. Then I added a User control in the project with same responses. In the user control I added a button and I added a button in the window as well. When I run the sample I donot see any of the icons (in window direct as well as within user control)

When I compare with the demo application I do not see any difference apart from the fact that in demo you have a separate class library for the icons.xaml.

Below is my code.

Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp.Demo"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/TestApp.Demo;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />-->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="50" 
 Height="50" 
Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
            <Rectangle Width="20" 
Height="20" 
Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" 
                    Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_city}" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </Button>
        <local:UCTest Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Below is the user control code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Demo.UCTest"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/TestApp.Demo;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Button Width="50" 
 Height="50" 
Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
                <Rectangle Width="20" 
Height="20" 
Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" 
                    Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_city}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Button>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Am I missing something here ?
•Girija

Comment: What is the path of Resources.xaml ?

Comment: When I installed the nugget, it created a folder "Resources" in my project and the Icons.xaml file in that . I tried all these possible ways but none worked : 1. <ResourceDictionary Source="/TestApp.Demo;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />  2. <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" /> 3. <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/TestApp.Demo;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to solve your problem.

First option is to use `StaticResource` instead `DynamicResource`.

```
<VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_city}" />
```

Second option is to put your resources to the `App.xaml`, so you can still use `DynamicResource`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Works thanks.... I went with the static resource approach as I load my WPF  window from another application (hosted) and I do not have the app.xaml